# L293DNE Always On

Tags: motor, microchip

I am hoping to put together a circuit that will control a slot car track from a 30V 3A power supply. I have used the L293DNE as I thought it would cope with the extra load.

The circuit is based on the lower half of this one, found on instructables [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-your-motors-with-L293D-and-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS)
[image]
[image]

Here is the assembled circuit

[image]

Red cable from the right is the unregulated voltage. The blue is the unregulated voltage ground (transformer). The regulator converts the voltage down to 5V and looks slightly different to the first diagram.

The issue I'm having is that the motor outputs are always on when the chip is powered. Any ideas why that could be? [Comparing my circuit to others](http://developeraspirations.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/l293dne-h-bridge/) doesn't show any major differences:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have left all four driver inputs floating. Use pull down resistors from the inputs to GND to force a low state when nothing drives the inputs (10K would be fine).
To make the motor turn connect 5v to one of the two driver inputs (per side), depending on the rotation direction you want.
To stop the motor(s) just disconnect Vcc from the driver inputs.

What I mean is like

[image]

Note that the two switched are independent, they can connect Vcc to one of the two driver inputs (per channel) or none.
I have omitted the capacitors for simplicity, they should be added in the real circuit.

Comment: Excellent! Just what I wanted, thank you. You mentioned a 5V input to drive the motor direction. Can I use PWM to adjust the motor output?

Comment: @MrNorm Sure you can, you can drive the enable line with PWM to control the motor speed and then use the two driver inputs with switches or some other device in order to select the rotation direction.

Comment: Thanks! Adding those seemed to do the trick. Unfortunately the connection to the transformer powering the circuit was loose. The circuit lost power a number of times and then the chip got VERY hot and started passing an increasing amount of voltage through the motor out pins. I think the chip has died, any ideas how that could have happened with the circuit?

Comment: @MrNorm How much current does the motor draw? The device can't dissipate much heat, maybe you need a heatsink for your application

Comment: It was 15v 3A but no motors were connected at that point in time as I was still testing the citcuit, it went straight to the ground rail.

Comment: @MrNorm What is the meaning of `went straight to the ground rail`? You mean you had the two outputs that connect to the motor shorted?

Comment: Thats correct, so it's essentially exactly like my picture, only with added capacitors for the inputs as per your suggestion.

Comment: @MrNorm Maybe I misunderstood, you mean that the motor in the images was replaced by a wire that shorts the outputs? Pin 3 and 6 connected together?

Comment: Oh no, not at all. Pin 3 goes through a 0.1uf capacitor and  into negative rail. Pin 6 goes through another 0.1uf capacitor into the negative rail also. [Here is the section of my circuit I am referring to](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aul16b4om70jh9s/Screenshot%202014-01-30%2019.30.22.png). Ignore the blue wires to the right.

Comment: @MrNorm OK, so these are the capacitors shown in the first schematic in your question, between each output and the ground. These serve no purpose when there is no motor connected and if you use PWM to switch the output fast with a low resistance path to ground missing (motor) I think they may be a cause of problem. Were you using PWM with the device when it got hot?

Comment: Ah OK, I thought the low resistance from lack of motor may have been the cause of the issue. I wasn't using PWM at the time but where the circuit was unstable anyway due to the transformer cutting out I believe it have have had a similar impact. I have another chip coming and will absolutely connect motors for when it arrives! Thanks for all your help and patience :)

Comment: @MrN  If you don't want to connect the motor you can connect a resistor in its place, for example 10 Ohm /10w to experiment.